# Article with parts of the body

Tags: articles

We use 'the' with body organs: 'There is a hole in THE heart'. Should we still use 'the' when we define the organ as in 'He complained of a sore throat' or 'He complained of an upset stomach'? Is it 'a sore throat/an upset stomach' or 'the sore throat/the upset stomach'?

Comment: I suggest that English Language Learners is a more suitable forum for basic questions of this sort. The [Tour] seems quite clear to me on that point.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, on first mention, the indefinite article is used:

- *He complained of [having] a sore throat.*
- *She has a grazed knee.*
- *Aloysius has a weak heart.*

Exceptions occur with post-specification:

> - *Chase said that Jay hadn't complained of the sore neck typical of meningitis, but ...*

[[Google; House.Fandom](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22complained+of+the+sore%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=JfuxYYneFaWx8gLDqpSQDw&ved=0ahUKEwjJhLuz4Nb0AhWlmFwKHUMVBfIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22complained+of+the+sore%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjoFCAAQkQI6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARCjAjoICAAQgAQQsQM6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgQIABBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgUIABCABDoLCAAQgAQQsQMQyQM6BQgAEJIDOggIABCxAxCRAjoICC4QgAQQsQM6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDOgUILhCABDoFCAAQsQM6BwgAEIAEEAo6CAgAEBYQChAeSgQIQRgAUABY_GRgwGloAHACeACAAWOIAZkNkgECMjSYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)]

and also with generic usages:

- The toe bone's connected to the foot bone, The foot bone's connected to the ankle bone, ....

> - *... law enforcement officer gives you the 'pen test' they are looking*
>   *for an involuntary jerking of the eyes*

[[Dayton DUI; Charles M. Rowland II](https://daytondui.com/vertical-gaze-nystagmus-test/)]

and when Poirot is cheekily importing French grammar into English.

Of course, if the part has already been mentioned, the definite article is required:

> - *How you can ease headaches yourself:*
>
> ... ... ...
>
> *do not sleep more than you usually would – it can make the headache worse*

[[NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/headaches/)]

> - *Wilson Yambo connected on so many good long‐range shots to the head last night that he outdid himself, injured **his right hand** and lost the
>   battle billed as the bantamweight championship of Puerto Rico to
>   Davey Vasquez of the Bronx.... According to his cornerman, Luis
>   Camacho, Yambo first complained of **the sore hand** after the fifth round
>   ....*

[[Al Harvin; The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1972/04/18/archives/vasquez-victor-in-forum-fight-hand-broken-yambo-quits-after-eight.html)] [Bolding mine to show prior reference.]

Note also the fixed-phrase usage in the post-modifying 'to the head' in the extract above. This is arguably also a generic usage. Such phrases are common. '[A pain] in the neck.' '[A smack] on the behind.' This is also the case with prepositional phrases acting as adverbials: '[Kicked] in the stomach.' '[Tapped] on the shoulder.' '[Cut] to the quick.'

Comment: You should show the transition to "the" in the second mention.

Comment: I think the distinction here is that *an* ailment could be any one of a number of ailments that have or will occur in a given body part, whereas one that is already mentioned is that specific ailment under discussion. When discussing a specific body part, you only have a specific number of them (unless something like "a hair", etc - although "the hair" refers to a person's hair as a whole), they are definite.

Answer (score 2):

(Adding to Edwin's answer)

There is typically no article before medical conditions that consist of a body part preceded by the occupation/activity in which the condition is common, for example:

> You have *tennis elbow / athlete's foot / swimmer's ear / runner's knee /  skier's thumb / jogger's heel / jogger's foot / jumper's knee / miner's lung*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the relevant discussion from [Collins COBUILD English Guides: Articles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0003705617), pp. 50–51:

> **6.13 Parts of the body**
>
> Names of parts of the body, like 'hand', 'face', and 'knee', are
> usually count nouns used with the indefinite or definite article
> according to the standard rules of use (see Chapters 3 and 4). We have
> also seen a special use of the definite article to refer generically
> to body parts (section 5.3 [the relevant part of that section is reproduced below]).
>
> There is also a use where we are thinking of parts of the body not as
> separate organs or limbs but as locations on the body. For this you
> can use the definite article.
>
> *They might dash out later and stab them in **the back.**
>  She had the urge to beat him over **the head.***
>
> It is possible to use the definite article with a singular noun even
> when there are two possible parts.
>
> *Stein took Breslow by **the arm.**
>  … to shake him by **the hand.**
>  It bit her on **the leg.**
>  He was wounded in **the
> leg** too.*
>
> Here there is no suggestion that Breslow has only one arm (mentioned
> before) or that 'he' has only one leg; the part of the body is all
> that is important, not which side.
>
> You use the definite article like this when the noun referring to the
> body part is included in a prepositional phrase ('in the back', 'by
> the arm') after a verb of touching or injuring ('shake', 'bite'), and
> the person whose body you are referring to has just been mentioned
> ('them', 'Breslow').
>
> When the noun comes straight after a verb such as 'grab' or after a
> verb and a preposition, for example 'step on', you have to use a
> possessive determiner like 'their' or 'his'; for example, you have to
> say 'I stepped on his foot' not 'I stepped on the foot'. Sometimes
> there are alternatives: 'I shook him by the hand' or 'I shook his
> hand'.
>
> *The black-haired youth grabbed **her arm** and shook her.
>  Robert touched **her cheek.***
>
> You can also use the definite article when referring to a touch, blow,
> or pain.
>
> *… giving me a friendly pat on **the shoulder.**
>  I have a pain in **the side.***

For completeness, here is the relevant part of section 5.3, which was mentioned above:

> **5.3 Singular count nouns with the definite article**
>
> …
>
> [The definite article] is also commonly used when doctors or other
> people are generalizing professionally about parts of the body.
>
> *This may flatten that side of **the head.** It won't hurt **the brain.**
>  This chapter deals with the lower part of **the leg.***

Comment: +1. Note that, although this source distinguishes the use of the definite article when "generalizing professionally" from "the standard rules of use", something similar is found in various other domains; hence e.g. "**The** Siberian tiger is often considered to be the largest tiger" [[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_tiger)], or "in Spain, **the** mayor is the most important and the key political official of the city" [[link (PDF)](https://rm.coe.int/local-and-regional-democracy-in-spain-recommendation-marc-cools-belgiu/168071969f)].